# How would you do specific origins to specific destinations using network analyst in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst

I'm working in ArcGIS Pro 2.5 and I have an Advanced license.

There will be 2 datasets:

1. about 400 points for origins (ZIP centroids)
2. about 40 points for destinations (healthcare facilities)

I already have a ZIP polygon feature class containing the number of visitors by ZIP going to particular healthcare facilities. Because of this, I already know which combinations of ZIPs go to which healthcare facilities. I previously used this feature class for a map series project (data driven pages in ArcMap) and set a page definition query to only display the amount of visitors by ZIP for one healthcare facility at a time. I know I'll need to convert the ZIP polygons to centroids, but I'm trying to determine the best approach to use the dataset to calculate the distance and drive time from each ZIP centroid to each healthcare facility.

So far my thought is that I could use OD Cost Matrix, load my ZIP centroid locations, and load 1 healthcare facility destination at a time, then solve. I imagine it wouldn't take long for each run with that amount of locations, but I'd still need to do that x40. Is there a better way to do this? I was thinking Route, but I'm not sure it'd be any faster. Is there a quick way to do that with ArcPy? Basically, I want to calculate distance/drive time to each of the 40 facilities for all 400 ZIPs. I don't need the lines, just the table.

Comment: I do not think 16000-combination is going to be a problem for network analysis. I advise you to feed them all into analysis and solve.

Comment: But there is no setting in OD cost to allow specific origins to specific destinations. They go to the nearest destination. Therefore I would need to do 40 separate runs with 1 destination at a time. Are you saying that’s the best approach?

Comment: AFAIK, it should be doing all-to-all by default. "Destinations to find" section of  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/od-cost-matrix.htm#ESRI_SECTION3_2C0874319C484838916F8D2046D6A316 says you should be able to.